# How to fix the issue "DrupalUserProcessor::drupalUserLogsIn(): Argument #1 ($account) must be of type Drupal\user\UserInterface" in Drupal 9?

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

After we upgrade to Drupal 9, we became to face the following error in all our drupal pages:

```
TypeError: Drupal\ldap_user\Processor\DrupalUserProcessor::drupalUserLogsIn(): 
Argument #1 ($account) must be of type Drupal\user\UserInterface, null given, called in 
portal/modules/ldap/ldap_user/src/Processor/GroupUserUpdateProcessor.php on line 302 in 
Drupal\ldap_user\Processor\DrupalUserProcessor->drupalUserLogsIn() (line 449 of 
modules/ldap/ldap_user/src/Processor/DrupalUserProcessor.php).
    
Drupal\ldap_user\Processor\DrupalUserProcessor->drupalUserLogsIn(NULL) (Line: 302)
Drupal\ldap_user\Processor\GroupUserUpdateProcessor->processAccount(Object, 'samaccountname') (Line: 246)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be hitting this [drupal bug](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3153455). The bug report has very detailed instructions on how to repair your website. In short:

**Export your configuration**

```
drush config:export
cd config/sync # the exact path will be printed out by drush
```

**Search for 'getCurrentUserId' in the old config**

```
grep -R "getCurrentUserId" .
```

**Open all affected files and replace**

```
default_value_callback: 'Drupal\node\Entity\Node::getCurrentUserId'
```

with

```
default_value_callback: 'Drupal\node\Entity\Node::getDefaultEntityOwner
```

**Re-Import your config**

```
drush config:import
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9, the `authexternal` module requires more mapped fields.

Go to `/admin/config/people/ldap/user_drupal` and map two fields: `User Id` and `UUID`.

In our case we map with Active Directory token `[samaccountname]`, but if you're using ldap you maybe use `uid`